# Sourcetree for Mac - Can no longer pull code and error message is ambiguous

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I tried to pull code utilizing Sourcetree from a repository I had pulled code from 2 days prior with no issue.  I am now getting this message.

The error message in the *Pulling Branch "master" From "origin"* progress window reads as follows:

```
git --no-optional-locks -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree fetch origin 
Completed with errors, see above
```

I've tried navigating to the repository in question via the terminal and making the `git` command in question there, in hopes of obtaining more information, but nothing further is provided.

Edit:  I suppose I should mention that I can still pull code on my Windows machine using the same account, and from the same repository, just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar error, when I saw the logs:

```
Unable to update local refs
```

[image: During mixed reset, duplicate references were generated]

I resolved this by removing the duplicate references

```
git remote prune origin
```

(or)

```
git gc — prune=now
```